# How can I add to HTML from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I've been trying to add data from JSON to HTML for days. Actually, I did it. But there is such a situation. I have an INDEX variable. Its value is zero at start. I have two trigger functions. One decreases the value of INDEX and the other increases the value. When one of the buttons is clicked, the value of the INDEX increases or decreases. When the value of INDEX changes, the data from JSON does not change. So, data is in the zero index does not replace the next one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    class Request {
        get(url) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => resolve(data)).catch(err => reject(err));
            })
        }
    }
    const Requesting = new Request();
    Requesting.get("js/carousel.json").then(data => {
        add(data);
    });

    const carousel_baslik = document.querySelector(".carousel-baslik");
    const carousel_metin = document.querySelector(".carousel-metin");
    const carousel_image = document.querySelector(".carousel-image");
    const counter = document.querySelector("#counter");
    const icon = document.querySelector("#icon-ground");
    const controller1 = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-controller")[0];
    const controller2 = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-controller")[1];
    var index = 0;
    controller1.addEventListener("click", geri);
    controller2.addEventListener("click", ileri);

    function geri() {
        index--;
        console.log(index);

    }

    function ileri() {
        index++;
        console.log(index);
    }

    function add(data) {
        carousel_baslik.textContent = data[index].baslik;
        carousel_metin.innerHTML = data[index].metin;
        carousel_image.src = data[index].image;
        counter.textContent = data[index].count;
        const img = `<img src="${data[index].icon}" class="w-100" alt="">`;
        icon.innerHTML = img;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change `icon.innerHTML` again, then you have to actually change it *again*.

Changing the value of `index` doesn't cause JavaScript to travel back in time to before you read the value of `index` to generate your `<img>` source code causing it to retroactively update the DOM.

You need to update the DOM *again*, **after** you give `index` a new value.

Comment: You were absolutely right man. I found the solution. Thank you so much :)